# How to set unique color for strings in PHPStorm?

Tags: phpstorm

How to set unique color for strings in PHPStorm?

I simply want this :

```
php echo " all text inside quotation marks is red " ;

$another_exemple = " all text inside quotation marks is red " ;
```

Comment: it doesn't work when its overwrite by SQL color , for exemple : $var = " SELECT * from blabla " ;

Comment: gosh it works ! makes ur answer for upvote ,thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To set color for **text strings** -- just do it in `Settings | Editor | Colors & Fonts | PHP | Strings`

**P.S.** You may need to uncheck "Inherit Attributes From" checkbox to be able to set custom color.